# Aurelia Master-Detail using the router without event aggregation

Tags: aurelia

I need to implement a routing use case where I have a list of items on a parent router that can be edited on a child router, like in the following image from Aurelia's [app-contacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWudT.png) sample app:

[image: aurelia's app-contacts sample]

There's a contacts list on the parent router and contact details for editing are on the child router.

In the app-contacts example all the communication between the parent and child router is done through a pub/sub mechanism (event aggregator):

```
activate(params, routeConfig){
this.routeConfig = routeConfig;

return this.api.getContactDetails(params.id).then(contact => {
  this.contact = contact;
  this.routeConfig.navModel.setTitle(contact.firstName);
  this.originalContact = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(contact));
  this.ea.publish(new ContactViewed(contact));
});
```

}

How can I implement something similar, but having the child router bound to the selected contact on the parent's router?

Comment: I think the `compose` tag and `model.bind` are what you are looking for (either setting up a viewmodel in the parent component, or making the detail a child component of the master).